# How to change partition_num in NebulaGraph database?

Tags: nebula-graph

The manual provides a syntax to create a space with a given partition number

```
CREATE SPACE [IF NOT EXISTS] <graph_space_name> (
[partition_num = <partition_number>,]
[replica_factor = <replica_number>,]
vid_type = {FIXED_STRING(<N>) | INT64}
)
[COMMENT = '<comment>'];
```

But if the space is created and a partition number is set.

Then how to change the partition number?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/3.ngql-guide/9.space-statements/1.create-space/), the `partition_num` can't be changed.

```
graph_space_name, partition_num, replica_factor, vid_type, and comment cannot be modified once set.
 To modify them, drop the current working graph space with DROP SPACE and create a new one with CREATE SPACE.
```